# PHP & SQL - How to add recurring items to seperate database

Tags: php, html, sql, wamp, pseudocode

Using php & sql, say I have 2 databases(a & b).  I want a user to be able to create a third database(c) with items from a & b.  How would I write the PHP to allow the user to select items from a & b from a list, and have them be able to save the results so that it can be later viewable and called from c?

Example :

```
a is composed of customers
b is composed of product
```

user selects a customer from "a", and then associates products from "b" to later be viewable as something as follows :

```
John Doe
apple
orange
banana
```

Thanks for all helping!  For my coding knowledge as of yet, I can create the databases in sql, but do not know how to join them in an "unlimited" manner in php, as displayed above.

Comment: You should read more about databases. You do not really want to store those things in separate databases, but in separate tables inside the same database, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table has the following structure

***tableA: customerID, customerName, customer...*
*tableB: productID, productName, product...***

You will need to create a third table which stores the customer ID and product ID. The schema will be:

***tableC: customerID, productID, qty, ...***

To insert the data, you will need to perform:

```
INSERT INTO tableC (customerID, productID, qty, ...)
```

Your retrieval SQL will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableC
```

```
This will return:
John Doe, apple
John Doe, orange
John Doe, banana
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew it had to be simple as such, no just a little research on the php side for search functions across database a & b(so user can find and select items), as well as code to dynamically add the next line item, and I am set!  Thanks a lot!